# Silverlight application will not install out of browser

Tags: silverlight, installation, out-of-browser

I have created a Silverlight application that runs OOB with extra features. We've taken a few machines and wiped them completely, installed XP and full service packs and updates and installed Silverlight for a few kiosks at a customer location. When I right click in the app and select Install Out of Browser, it does nothing. The option is there to install out of browser, but it does nothing. Installing the application OOB works fine on all other machines besides these two Dells. They're running XP SP3 + IE8. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the user running the OOB application an administrator?  
Are you getting any errors in the event log that can help?
Does the install dialog come up at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with the help from another programmer here at the office.

We checked to be sure that the user running the application had Admin rights, and anything else we could think of, but it was something I didn't expect... although it made sense after we figured it out.

Don't use PNG files as the icons for the application if you want your app to run on Windows XP. They work fine in-browser, Macs and any Windows OS at or above Vista. However, when you try to install the application OOB either through menus or the SLLAUNCHER.EXE method, it will fail silently because *XP cannot handle 32-bit PNG files*.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user running the application has rights to the temp directories.  This will prevent the application from working on a computer where the user rights have been altered (as is common for kiosk applications)